# Is there any way to draw line by it's center in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making a class that draws axis for a graph. And the result should look like this:

[image]

And I want to draw lines which represents scale by only passing the coords of their centers, length and orientation (vertical or hoisontal) to vertex shader by calling `glDrawArrays()`. Is the any way to do this?

[image]

I have been searching for hours, but only way of drawing lines I found is to call `glDrawArrays()` with `GL_LINES` and pass an array of lines begin and end coords.

Comment: *...to draw lines which represents scale by only passing the coords of their centers, length and orientation (vertical or hoisontal) to vertex shader...* I don't understand what this means. But from your picture, I'm not sure why you're asking about drawing a line "from it's center". The picture shows four lines drawn from one end, a common point, to separate points on the axes. Referencing your drawing, exactly what points on those lines (or rays) do you know?

Comment: Who said the values passed via `glDrawArrays` to the shader program had to be the  beginning and ending vertices?  They can represent whatever you want so long as you use them correctly.

Comment: Why can't you use begin and end coords?

Comment: I need to draw lines (small stripes on axises) by only 1 coordinate (theirs centers). Is there any way to draw lines by passing only 1 argument per line?

Comment: You can do this easily with geometry shaders  ... converting `Point` primitive into `Line` ... and just have the axis normal direction as single `uniform vec2` the length might be passed as anything like 1D texture coordinate or even color ...

Comment: "*I need to draw lines (small stripes on axises) by only 1 coordinate (theirs centers).*" Why? You can convert a center+length to two points *trivially* on the CPU. So just do that and feed OpenGL what it needs.